# Content Editor Search by ID returns no results

Tags: content-search, content-editor

I am very new to Sitecore, going through training, trying to get certified.

In the `Content Editor`, I am trying to find an item by it's `ID / GUID`.

I can navigate down into the tree, find an item, copy its ID, go back up to the root folder `/Sitecore`, and do a search with the filter for ID.  I paste the entire ID in, with curly braces.  The item is not found.

If I copy the ID for the Home folder, `/Content/Home`, then the search finds the item.

Why doesn't the search for ID filter work on all items?

RolanCCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **rebuild your indexes** to use the search feature.

1. Log in to the Launchpad.
2. Open the Control Panel.
3. In the Indexing section, click Indexing Manager.
4. In the Indexing Manager dialog box, select the indexes you want to rebuild, and click Rebuild:

[image]